# Derivative of a generalized hypergeometric function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Let $$f(a)={_2F_3}\left(\begin{array}c1,\ 1\\\tfrac32,\ 1-a,\ 2+a\end{array}\middle|-\pi^2\right).$$
How to find $f'(0)$ in a closed form?

[image: graph]

Comment: Search for a closed form for the numeric value of $f'(0)$ suggests $\displaystyle\frac{\text{Ci}(2\pi)-\ln(2\pi)-\gamma}{\pi^2}$ (agrees to at least 1000 decimal digits).

Comment: [This identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/20/01/02/0002/) on the Wolfram Functions site looks like it could provide the right starting point.

Comment: Note: if anyone chooses to use that identity, the $F$ on the RHS is the [Kampe de Feriet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function $f(a)$ has the following integral representation in terms of the [Struve function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StruveFunction.html) $\operatorname{H}_{\nu}{(z)}$:

$$\begin{align}
f(a)
&={_2F_3}{\left(1,1;\frac32,1-a,2+a;-\pi^2\right)}\\
&=(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}$$

---

**Proof:** The integral representation above is a corollary of the following integral representations of the generalized hypergeometric function ${_2F_3}$ ([ref.](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F3/07/01/01/0001/)), the generalized hypergeometric function ${_1F_2}$ ([ref.](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F2/07/01/01/0001/)), and the confluent hypergeometric function ${_0F_1}$ ([ref.](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric0F1/07/01/01/0004/)):

$${_2F_3}{\left(a_1,a_2;b_1,b_2,b_3;z\right)}=\frac{\Gamma{\left(b_3\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a_2\right)}\Gamma{\left(b_3-a_2\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a_2-1}(1-t)^{-a_2+b_3-1}{_1F_2}{\left(a_1;b_1,b_2;zt\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t;$$

$${_1F_2}{\left(a_1;b_1,b_2;zt\right)}=\frac{\Gamma{\left(b_2\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a_1\right)}\Gamma{\left(b_2-a_1\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}u^{a_1-1}(1-u)^{-a_1+b_2-1}{_0F_1}{\left(;b_1;ztu\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u;$$

$${_0F_1}{\left(;b_1;ztu\right)}=\frac{2\,\Gamma{\left(b_1\right)}}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma{\left(b_1-\frac12\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}(1-\xi^2)^{b_1-\frac32}\cosh{\left(2\,\sqrt{ztu}\,\xi\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\xi.$$

Note that the last integral above reduces to an extremely simple trigonometric integral in the special case where $b_1=\frac32$ (which is of course true of the problem at hand).

$$\begin{align}
{_2F_3}{\left(1,1;\frac32,1-a,2+a;-\pi^2\right)}
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(2+a\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(1\right)}\Gamma{\left(2+a-1\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}t^{1-1}(1-t)^{-1+2+a-1}{_1F_2}{\left(1;\frac32,1-a;-\pi^2t\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(2+a\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(1+a\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{a}{_1F_2}{\left(1;\frac32,1-a;-\pi^2t\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=(1+a)\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{a}{_1F_2}{\left(1;\frac32,1-a;-\pi^2t\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t.
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
{_1F_2}{\left(1;\frac32,1-a;-\pi^2t\right)}
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(1-a\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(1\right)}\Gamma{\left(1-a-1\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}u^{1-1}(1-u)^{-1+(1-a)-1}{_0F_1}{\left(;\frac32;-\pi^2tu\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(1-a\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(-a\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^{-(a+1)}{_0F_1}{\left(;\frac32;-\pi^2tu\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-a\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^{-(a+1)}{_0F_1}{\left(;\frac32;-\pi^2tu\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u.
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
{_0F_1}{\left(;\frac32;-\pi^2tu\right)}
&=\frac{2\,\Gamma{\left(\frac32\right)}}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac32-\frac12\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}(1-\xi^2)^{\frac32-\frac32}\cosh{\left(2\,\sqrt{-\pi^2tu}\,\xi\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=\frac{2\,\Gamma{\left(\frac32\right)}}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma{\left(1\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\cosh{\left(2\,\sqrt{-\pi^2tu}\,\xi\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=\frac{2\,\Gamma{\left(\frac32\right)}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}\cos{\left(2\,\pi\,\sqrt{tu}\,\xi\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\cos{\left(2\,\pi\,\sqrt{tu}\,\xi\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=\frac{\sin{\left(2\pi\sqrt{tu}\right)}}{2\pi\sqrt{tu}}.
\end{align}$$

Next comes the back-substitution. Insert the result for ${_0F_1}$ into the integral for ${_1F_2}$, and then substitute $u=v^2$:

$$\begin{align}
{_1F_2}{\left(1;\frac32,1-a;-\pi^2t\right)}
&=-a\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^{-(a+1)}{_0F_1}{\left(;\frac32;-\pi^2tu\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-a\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^{-(a+1)}\frac{\sin{\left(2\pi\sqrt{tu}\right)}}{2\pi\sqrt{tu}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-a\int_{0}^{1}(1-v^2)^{-(a+1)}\frac{\sin{\left(2\pi\sqrt{t}\,v\right)}}{\pi\sqrt{t}}\,\mathrm{d}v\\
&=-\frac{a}{\pi\sqrt{t}}\int_{0}^{1}(1-v^2)^{-(a+1)}\sin{\left(2\pi\sqrt{t}\,v\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v.
\end{align}$$

The next step after reaching the last line above is where the Struve function finally makes its appearance. The integral in previous line is precisely the form required by this [integral representation of the Struve](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/StruveH/07/01/01/0001/) function. Hence,

$$\begin{align}
{_1F_2}{\left(1;\frac32,1-a;-\pi^2t\right)}
&=-\frac{a}{\pi\sqrt{t}}\int_{0}^{1}(1-v^2)^{-(a+1)}\sin{\left(2\pi\sqrt{t}\,v\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v\\
&=-\frac{a}{\pi\sqrt{t}}\frac{\pi^{a+1}}{2}t^{\frac{a}{2}+\frac14}\Gamma{(-a)}\operatorname{H}_{-a-\frac12}{(2\pi\sqrt{t})}\\
&=\frac12\pi^{a}t^{\frac{a}{2}-\frac14}\Gamma{(1-a)}\operatorname{H}_{-a-\frac12}{(2\pi\sqrt{t})}.
\end{align}$$

Finally, upon substituting $x=\sqrt{t}$,

$$\begin{align}
f(a)
&={_2F_3}{\left(1,1;\frac32,1-a,2+a;-\pi^2\right)}\\
&=(1+a)\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{a}{_1F_2}{\left(1;\frac32,1-a;-\pi^2t\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=(1+a)\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{a}\cdot\frac12\pi^{a}t^{\frac{a}{2}-\frac14}\Gamma{(1-a)}\operatorname{H}_{-a-\frac12}{(2\pi\sqrt{t})}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\pi^{a}(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{a}t^{\frac{a}{2}+\frac14}\operatorname{H}_{-a-\frac12}{(2\pi\sqrt{t})}\,\frac{1}{2t^{1/2}}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\pi^{a}(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^{a}x^{a+\frac12}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\pi^a(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\int_{0}^{1}\left[x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}$$

---

Using the integral representation,

$$\begin{align}
f{(a)}
&=(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{align}$$

differentiate $f(a)$ with respect to $a$ using the product rule:

$$\begin{align}
f^\prime{(a)}
&=\frac{d}{da}\left[(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\right]\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x+\\&~~~~~(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}$$

Evaluating the derivative at $a=0$, and using the fact that $\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}{(2\pi\,x)}=\frac{\sin{(2\pi x)}}{\pi}$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
f^\prime{(0)}
&=\frac{d}{da}\bigg{|}_{a=0}\left[(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\right]\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x+\\&~~~~~\Gamma{(1)}\frac{d}{da}\bigg{|}_{a=0}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{d}{da}\bigg{|}_{a=0}\left[(1+a)\Gamma{(1-a)}\right]\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin{(2\pi x)}}{\pi}\,\mathrm{d}x+\\&~~~~~\frac{d}{da}\bigg{|}_{a=0}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{d}{da}\bigg{|}_{a=0}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}$$

Using the [Leibniz integral rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html),

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left[\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left[\pi x(1-x^2)\right]^{a}\sqrt{x}\left[\ln{\left(\pi x(1-x^2)\right)}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}-\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\begin{align}
f^\prime{(0)}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\left[\ln{\left(\pi x(1-x^2)\right)}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}{(2\pi\,x)}-\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12-a}{(2\pi\,x)}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\left[\ln{\left(\pi x(1-x^2)\right)}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}{(2\pi\,x)}-\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}^{(1,0)}{(2\pi\,x)}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left[\ln{\left(\pi x(1-x^2)\right)}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}{(2\pi\,x)}-\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}^{(1,0)}{(2\pi\,x)}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left[\ln{\left(\pi x(1-x^2)\right)}\frac{\sin{(2\pi x)}}{\pi}-\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}^{(1,0)}{(2\pi\,x)}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\ln{\left(\pi x(1-x^2)\right)}\sin{(2\pi x)}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}^{(1,0)}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}$$

---

To evaluate the derivative of $f(a)$ with respect to $a$ at $a=0$, it will also be helpful to know that

$$\sqrt{x}\,\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}^{(1,0)}{(2\pi\,x)}=\frac{\left(2\operatorname{Ci}{(2\pi\,x)}-\operatorname{Ci}{(4\pi\,x)}\right)\sin{(2\pi\,x)}-\left(2\operatorname{Si}{(2\pi\,x)}-\operatorname{Si}{(4\pi\,x)}\right)\cos{(2\pi\,x)}}{\pi}.$$

From here, it is not too difficult to show that the conjectured value proposed by @VladimirReshetnikov is indeed correct:

$$\begin{align}
f^\prime(0)
&=-\frac{\operatorname{Ci}{(2\pi)}-\operatorname{Ci}{(4\pi)}+\ln{2}}{2\pi^2}-\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\,\operatorname{H}_{-\frac12}^{(1,0)}{(2\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{\operatorname{Ci}{(2\pi)}-\operatorname{Ci}{(4\pi)}+\ln{2}}{2\pi^2}-\\
&~~~~\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(2\operatorname{Ci}{(2\pi\,x)}-\operatorname{Ci}{(4\pi\,x)}\right)\sin{(2\pi\,x)}-\left(2\operatorname{Si}{(2\pi\,x)}-\operatorname{Si}{(4\pi\,x)}\right)\cos{(2\pi\,x)}}{\pi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{\operatorname{Ci}{(2\pi)}-\operatorname{Ci}{(4\pi)}+\ln{2}}{2\pi^2}-\frac{-3\operatorname{Ci}{(2\pi)}+\operatorname{Ci}{(4\pi)}+2\ln{2\pi}}{2\pi^2}+\frac{\ln{(2)}-2\gamma}{2\pi^2}\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{Ci}{(2\pi)}-\ln{2\pi}-\gamma}{\pi^2}.~~\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you source the integral representation and identity you use at the start?